# req.body returning undefined with body-parser packages installed

Tags: node.js, express, post

I'm trying to run a post method in express but I've run into a problem trying to get the post parameters within req.body. I've installed the body-parser package and have this within my app.js file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

I've tried the code with both the extended set to true and false. When I run this piece of code, I get returned {}.

```
app.post("/postfunction", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: show us your html, that will be sending this post request to the server

Comment: This is the request Im trying to send: http://localhost:3000/postfunction?key1=test1&key2=test2.

Comment: i can't access your localhost o.O . you should use `req.query` instead of `req.body`

Comment: POST data is submitted by form input fields with name attributes, GET data is passed by query strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


app.post('/form',function(req, res){
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    setTimeout(function(){

        res.send(JSON.stringify({
        firstName: req.body.firstName || null,
        lastName: req.body.lastName || null
        }));

    }, 1000)

  console.log('you posted: First Name: ' + req.body.firstName + ', Last Name: ' + 
    req.body.lastName);
  });

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running. Point your browser to: http://localhost:3000');
 });
```